# Authenticate user on Sub-domain and remain logged in on parent domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, forms-authentication

I have two sites:
www.forums.mysite.com
and www.mysite.com

The forums already has authentication set up and I'd like to use it.

I'm using C# MVC .NET 4.5

I have created two sites in IIS 8.5: mysite and forums

**mysite bindings:**

- Type: HTTP
- IP address: All Unnasigned
- Port: 80
- Host name: www.mysite.com

**forums bindings:**

- Type: HTTP
- IP address: All Unnasigned
- Port: 80
- Host name: www.forums.mysite.com

I have also added the domains to my **host file**:

- myip     www.mysite.com
- myip     www.forums.mysite.com

I have added the MachineKey to both applications Web.config files and the keys are identical:

```
<machineKey validationKey="C50B3C89CB21F4F1422FF158A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D9401E3400267682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE" decryptionKey="8A9BE8FD67AF6979E7D20198CFEA50DD3D3799C77AF2B72F" validation="SHA1" />
```

In the controller of the subdomain (Forums), a user logs in and I have modified the cookie as follows:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, model.RememberMe);
var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, model.RememberMe);
cookie.Domain = "mysite.com"; //this is the parent domain
//I've also tried with .mysite.com
Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
```

I can log in via the forums but then when I go to the main site (mysite.com), I am not logged in... I don't understand why not.

As a test in mysite.com/home/index.cshtml (the home page), I have added this:

```
<h1>
  Logged in:  @User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
</h1>
```

but the result is always false, even though both sites have the same .ASPXAUTH cookie...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, domain should be `.mysite.com` (leading dot), not `mysite.com`.

**Upd.**

Also, problem may be with leading `www` in your's domain names. Try set cookies domain to `www.mysite.com` or `.www.mysite.com` (or eliminate `www` in your's config, its just an archaic junk :))

**Upd. 2**

Looks like there is problems with setting cookies for parent domains (take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/153409/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com), for example), which is understandable, from some point of view.

Can suggest only following:

1. On user-login in subdomain, take auth data.
2. Serialize auth data and send it to parent domain to some script like `www.mysite.com/keep-logined?c=<encoded_auth_data>`.
3. In that `keep-logined` script unserialize auth data and manually set cookie for root domain.
4. Redirect user back to subdomain, (can supply `keep-logined` script with `redirect-back` url.

*Note: make sure to protect that `keep-logined` script and supplied auth data from hacking by some sort of encoding or key-passing.*

Comment: just tried this but still not working. Deleted cookies to be safe, too.